# [BUG]: One button should display 2 activities

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am new there and I hope I'll get an early answer. I make my first Android application and I want to make something special: I want one button to make an activity displayed if the user enters "1" in the numberpicker, and to display an other activity if the user enters an other number.
But with the next code, it always display the first activity (named "trip"). Can somebody help me please?
Please let me know if you need anything else to answer me.

```
public class numberoftrips extends AppCompatActivity  {
private Button btnNext2;
private EditText nbtrip;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_numberoftrips);
    btnNext2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext2);
    nbtrip=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.nbtrip1);
    final int n=Integer.parseInt(nbtrip.getText().toString());
    btnNext2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick (View view) {
            if (n==1){
                Intent myIntent =new Intent(getBaseContext(), trip.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
            }
            else{
                Intent myIntent =new Intent(getBaseContext(), ID_informations.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

PS: Sorry for my english, I am french.

Comment: your line `final int n =......`  remove it from its original place and put it in onclick method

Comment: It works, thank you very much. 
What if I need the number "n" in the other activities?

Answer (score 0):

Get the text inside EditText after you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's normal.

The number you speak about, is `n` if i'm right.

When your activity starting and start your `onCreate()` function, she initiate n at the value of the contain of `nbtrip` but at the begin of the activity. 
If you want to get the value of your EditText **after** that you change his text, you have two possibility

1 : set a changeTextListener

```
public class numberoftrips extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btnNext2;
    private EditText nbtrip;

    // add this here is necessary. If you declare it in a function
    // and use it in a listener, it must be final, and you will not change it.
    private int myActuallyValue = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numberoftrips);
        btnNext2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext2);
        nbtrip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nbtrip1);


//        final int n=Integer.parseInt(nbtrip.getText().toString());

        nbtrip.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // when the text change this function is automaticaly called and
                // you will get the charSequance, put in a String object
                // and get the int of the character of the String object.
                myActuallyValue = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(s));
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        btnNext2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // when you click on the button, you get the saved value when 
                // you edited your EditText
                if (myActuallyValue == 1) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), trip.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                } else {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ID_informations.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

2 : get the value at the moment when you click on the button

```
public class numberoftrips extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btnNext2;
    private EditText nbtrip;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numberoftrips);
        btnNext2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext2);
        nbtrip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nbtrip1);

        btnNext2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // here, you get the charSequance of the editText (after the onCreate finished)
                // then you get the String object of the charSequence with .toString
                // and you get the int value of the String object with Integer.valueOf()
                if (Integer.valueOf(nbtrip.getText().toString()) == 1) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), trip.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                } else {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ID_informations.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }
            }
        });   
    }
}
```